# Comment Notification with Message Stack / Message Notify

Tags: 8, comments, notifications, message-subscribe

The message stack has three main modules: Message, Message Notify and Message Subscribe.

One thing that it can do, is notifying node author of comments in their nodes. This is very much needed feature. At least that's the impression I get.

Can anyone help on how to setup Message Notify to let the node author they got a new comment on their node? Unfortunately there isn't that much documentation on how to do this.

I have installed the Message stack but don't know where to go from there.

Have looked at other options as well. Here are my findings.

There is the Comment Notify module, but there is not very much support at the moment and a lot of open issues. I have installed it but isn't enabled by default for users when they register on the site.

Rules for Drupal 8 does not support this feature yet.

Comment: For those who are looking for help with this take a look at https://vimeo.com/63919900